# Need a little bit of help in finishing query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I've got such query

```
SELECT
CDV.SetId
,CDV.DateImported
,CDV.ProductName
,sum(CDV.TransferedCapital) as [TransferedCapital]
,sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end) as [WithdrawValue]
,sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)-sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end) as [Left]
,(sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end)/sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)*100) as [Withdraw%]
,sum(CDV.PaymentValue) as [PaymentValue]
from
CaseDetailsView as CDV
join CaseActionHistory as CA on CA.CaseDetailId = CDV.CaseDetailsId
join PaymentCaseHistory as PCH on PCH.CaseDetailsId = CDV.CaseDetailsId
join PaymentSession as PS on PS.SessionId = PCH.SessionId
where
(CDV.ClientId = @ClientId or @ClientId IS NULL)
and
(CA.IsDeleted IS NULL or CA.IsDeleted <> 'True')
group by
CDV.SetId, CDV.DateImported, CDV.ProductName
order by
CDV.SetId
```

And I got "small" (read as: huge) problems with finishing it.

I need to add such field:

datepart(week,PS.SessionDate)

Without this one query works simply perfectly.

After adding this one I got something like:

```
SELECT
CDV.SetId
,CDV.DateImported
,CDV.ProductName
,sum(CDV.TransferedCapital) as [TransferedCapital]
,sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end) as [WithdrawValue]
,sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)-sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end) as [Left]
,(sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end)/sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)*100) as [Withdraw%]
,sum(CDV.PaymentValue) as [PaymentValue]
,datepart(week,PS.SessionDate) as [SessionDate]
from
CaseDetailsView as CDV
join CaseActionHistory as CA on CA.CaseDetailId = CDV.CaseDetailsId
join PaymentCaseHistory as PCH on PCH.CaseDetailsId = CDV.CaseDetailsId
join PaymentSession as PS on PS.SessionId = PCH.SessionId
where
(CDV.ClientId = @ClientId or @ClientId IS NULL)
and
(CA.IsDeleted IS NULL or CA.IsDeleted <> 'True')
group by
CDV.SetId, CDV.DateImported, CDV.ProductName, datepart(week, PS.SessionDate)
order by
CDV.SetId
```

However query doesn't show all values. Of course that's because of using "inner join".

But when I replaced inner join with left join like below:

```
SELECT
CDV.SetId
,CDV.DateImported
,CDV.ProductName
,sum(CDV.TransferedCapital) as [TransferedCapital]
,sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end) as [WithdrawValue]
,sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)-sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end) as [Left]
,(sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end)/sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)*100) as [Withdraw%]
,sum(CDV.PaymentValue) as [PaymentValue]
,datepart(week,PS.SessionDate) as [SessionDate]
from
CaseDetailsView as CDV
join CaseActionHistory as CA on CA.CaseDetailId = CDV.CaseDetailsId
left join PaymentCaseHistory as PCH on PCH.CaseDetailsId = CDV.CaseDetailsId
left join PaymentSession as PS on PS.SessionId = PCH.SessionId
where
(CDV.ClientId = @ClientId or @ClientId IS NULL)
and
(CA.IsDeleted IS NULL or CA.IsDeleted <> 'True')
group by
CDV.SetId, CDV.DateImported, CDV.ProductName, datepart(week, PS.SessionDate)
order by
CDV.SetId
```

Values get multiplied.

Ideas?

---

Based on tries, tests etc etc I finished with sth like:

```
SELECT
CDV.SetId
,CDV.DateImported
,CDV.ProductName
,COALESCE(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital),0) as [TransferedCapital]
,COALESCE(sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end),0) as [WithdrawValue]
,COALESCE(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)-sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end),0) as [Left]
,COALESCE((sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end)/sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)*100),0) as [Withdraw%]
,COALESCE(sum(PCH.PaymentValue),0) as [PaymentValue]
,COALESCE(datediff(week,CDV.DateImported, PS.SessionDate),0) as [Week]
from
CaseActionHistory as CA
join CaseDetailsView as CDV on CA.CaseDetailId = CDV.CaseDetailsId
join PaymentCaseHistory as PCH on PCH.ActionArchiveId = CA.CaseActionId
join PaymentSession as PS on PS.SessionId = PCH.SessionId
where
(CDV.ClientId = @ClientId or @ClientId IS NULL)
and
(CA.IsDeleted IS NULL or CA.IsDeleted <> 'True')
and
(CDV.SetId = @SetId or @SetId IS NULL)
group by
CDV.SetId, CDV.DateImported, CDV.ProductName, datediff(week,CDV.DateImported, PS.SessionDate)
order by
CDV.SetId, datediff(week,CDV.DateImported, PS.SessionDate)
```

The query itself works good. I just need one more thing inside of it:

A row which shows sum of

```
,COALESCE(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital),0) as [TransferedCapital]
,COALESCE(sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end),0) as [WithdrawValue]
,COALESCE(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)-sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end),0) as [Left]
,COALESCE((sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end)/sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)*100),0) as [Withdraw%]
,COALESCE(sum(PCH.PaymentValue),0) as [PaymentValue]
```

for whole SetId. I thought about UNION but may it work?

---

Query with UNION:

```
SELECT
CDV.SetId
,CDV.DateImported
,CDV.ProductName
,COALESCE(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital),0) as [TransferedCapital]
,COALESCE(sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end),0) as [WithdrawValue]
,COALESCE(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)-sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end),0) as [Left]
,COALESCE((sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end)/sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)*100),0) as [Withdraw%]
,COALESCE(sum(PCH.PaymentValue),0) as [PaymentValue]
,COALESCE(datediff(week,CDV.DateImported, PS.SessionDate),0) as [Week]
from
CaseActionHistory as CA
join CaseDetailsView as CDV on CA.CaseDetailId = CDV.CaseDetailsId
join PaymentCaseHistory as PCH on PCH.ActionArchiveId = CA.CaseActionId
join PaymentSession as PS on PS.SessionId = PCH.SessionId
where
(CDV.ClientId = @ClientId or @ClientId IS NULL)
and
(CA.IsDeleted IS NULL or CA.IsDeleted <> 'True')
and
(CDV.SetId = @SetId or @SetId IS NULL)
group by
CDV.SetId, CDV.DateImported, CDV.ProductName, datediff(week,CDV.DateImported, PS.SessionDate)
UNION ALL
SELECT
CDV.SetId
,CDV.DateImported
,CDV.ProductName
,COALESCE(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital),0) as [TransferedCapital]
,COALESCE(sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end),0) as [WithdrawValue]
,COALESCE(sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)-sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end),0) as [Left]
,COALESCE((sum(case when CA.CaseActionDefinitionId = 87 then CDV.TransferedCapital else 0 end)/sum(CDV.TransferedCapital)*100),0) as [Withdraw%]
,COALESCE(sum(CDV.PaymentValue),0) as [PaymentValue]
,NULL
from
CaseActionHistory as CA
join CaseDetailsView as CDV on CA.CaseDetailId = CDV.CaseDetailsId
where
(CDV.ClientId = @ClientId or @ClientId IS NULL)
and
(CA.IsDeleted IS NULL or CA.IsDeleted <> 'True')
and
(CDV.SetId = @SetId or @SetId IS NULL)
group by
CDV.SetId, CDV.DateImported, CDV.ProductName
order by
CDV.SetId
```

Comment: Have you see how join works? - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

Comment: Yes, I have, but still it's not solving my problem. I wouldn't bother you if I could manage with it on my own.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean with "for whole SetId". Can you explain more about that, please?

Comment: http://oi39.tinypic.com/24f0h6v.jpg  -> with red square I marked result of 2nd query. Updated first post with current look of query. I noticed that join "join CaseDetailsView as CDV on CA.CaseDetailId = CDV.CaseDetailsId" in 2nd query cause multiplying values.

Answer (score 0):

Change group by clause:

```
group by CDV.SetId, CDV.DateImported, CDV.ProductName, PS.SessionDate
```

Comment: Nope. Doesn't change anything. Values are still multiplied and same weeks are not counted as 1, so for example I have 3 records for 36 week for same SetId

Comment: Can you post an image about your ERD?

Comment: Can't unfortunately. However I can tell you that relations used in query are the only possible one which can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

I couldn't try this one, 'cause I don't have SQLServer at work.

```
select TBL1.*
      ,(TBL1.TRANSFEREDCAPITAL + TBL1.WITHDRAWVALUE + TBL1.left + TBL1.WITHDRAW% + TBL1.PAYMENTVALUE) as [TOTALSUM]
from   (select CDV.SETID
              ,CDV.DATEIMPORTED
              ,CDV.PRODUCTNAME
              ,COALESCE(sum(CDV.TRANSFEREDCAPITAL), 0) as [TRANSFEREDCAPITAL]
              ,COALESCE(sum(case
                                when CA.CASEACTIONDEFINITIONID = 87 then
                                 CDV.TRANSFEREDCAPITAL
                                else
                                 0
                            end), 0) as [WITHDRAWVALUE]
              ,COALESCE(sum(CDV.TRANSFEREDCAPITAL) - sum(case
                                                             when CA.CASEACTIONDEFINITIONID = 87 then
                                                              CDV.TRANSFEREDCAPITAL
                                                             else
                                                              0
                                                         end), 0) as [left]
              ,COALESCE((sum(case
                                 when CA.CASEACTIONDEFINITIONID = 87 then
                                  CDV.TRANSFEREDCAPITAL
                                 else
                                  0
                             end) / sum(CDV.TRANSFEREDCAPITAL) * 100), 0) as [WITHDRAW%]
              ,COALESCE(sum(PCH.PAYMENTVALUE), 0) as [PAYMENTVALUE]
              ,COALESCE(DATEDIFF(WEEK, CDV.DATEIMPORTED, PS.SESSIONDATE), 0) as [WEEK]
        from   CASEACTIONHISTORY as CA
        join   CASEDETAILSVIEW as CDV
        on     CA.CASEDETAILID = CDV.CASEDETAILSID
        join   PAYMENTCASEHISTORY as PCH
        on     PCH.ACTIONARCHIVEID = CA.CASEACTIONID
        join   PAYMENTSESSION as PS
        on     PS.SESSIONID = PCH.SESSIONID
        where  (CDV.CLIENTID = @CLIENTID or @CLIENTID is null)
               and (CA.ISDELETED is null or CA.ISDELETED <> 'True')
               and (CDV.SETID = @SETID or @SETID is null)
        group  by CDV.SETID
                 ,CDV.DATEIMPORTED
                 ,CDV.PRODUCTNAME
                 ,DATEDIFF(WEEK, CDV.DATEIMPORTED, PS.SESSIONDATE)
        order  by CDV.SETID
                 ,DATEDIFF(WEEK, CDV.DATEIMPORTED, PS.SESSIONDATE)) as TBL1;
```

Comment: Column PAYMENTSESSION.SessionDate is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause + Invalid name of column SessionDate + Can't connect CDV.SetId

Comment: Off course about SessionDate on last "order by". Test now please.

Comment: "Invalid column TBL1.SessionDate" but I just removed spaces in subquery, however it still requires all fields to be in main query so the results of your query are same as mine (multiplied values :) )

Comment: Updated first post with additional info. Take a look please.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the query, you don't seem to be using PaymentCaseHistory (PCH) or PaymentSession (PS) anywhere but in your new SessionDate field.

So the most obvious first conclusion would be that those two tables above contain numerous different week numbers per each prior result from CaseDetailsView and CaseActionHistory.

You can try this out by replacing your **datepart(week,PS.SessionDate)** as [SessionDate] with MAX(DATEPART(WEEK, PS.SessionDate)) and see what happens. Also, to group by it you need to add the same condition in the GROUP BY clause. IE:

```
SELECT .... datepart(week,PS.SessionDate) as [SessionDate]
FROM ....
GROUP BY ... , datepart(week,PS.SessionDate)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not really why what I wanted.. Values are still different than expected. I suppose it's connected with "join" clauses. What is more (if it would change anything) I found out that there's a way to connect CaseActionHistory with PaymentSession table using 'ArchiveId' column.

Comment: Updated first post with additional info. Take a look please.